# SFTP works but FTP not

Tags: ubuntu, ftp

i can connect successfully to my server using SFTP, but I try to connect using FTP and i get `incorrect password` error.

I am using vsftpd on an ubuntu 14.04.

Is there a reason FTP is doing that for this particular user? Because I tried to FTP using another user and it worked just fine.

Comment: SFTP or FTPS? SFTP isn't related to FTP at all - it uses ssh, and depending on your setup your FTP users and system users may be independent of each other

Comment: It's SFTP.

So what would be a reason that makes FTP work for one user but not another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working after alot of research:

change  this line

`pam_service_name=svftpd`

to this line

`pam_service_name=ftp`

in /etc/vsftpd.conf

Comment: actually, I think that *is* the answer.

Answer (score 0):

SFTP is the *ssh file transfer protocol* - Its not related to FTP at all. The 'encrypted' varient of FTP is FTPS.

Unfortunately, there's not enough information for a definitive answer but the ubuntu page on [vsftp suggests a few possibilities](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd).

The one that seems most plausible is that you have ftp access restricted to specific users

Check for lines that say

```
userlist_deny=NO
userlist_enable=YES
userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.allowed_users
```

This specific config dosen't deny any users explicitly but only allows users in a specific list to access. Likewise check if there's a denied list.

Another possibility is that vsftp is set up for virtual accounts, and there's an identical account name and password for FTP and system for one user and not the other.

Comment: That wasn't it, already checked white/black listing.